# OnBlur event not being fired on clicking of a commandButton?

Tags: jsf-2

I have developed a composite component as follows...

```
<composite:implementation>   
        <div class="numericBox">
            <h:inputText id="txtInput"
                         size="#{cc.attrs.maxLength}"
                         converterMessage="#{cc.attrs.converterMessage}"
                         validatorMessage="#{cc.attrs.validatorMessage}"
                         required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
                         requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredMessage}"
                         minlength="#{cc.attrs.minLength}"
                         maxlength="#{cc.attrs.maxLength}"
                         value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="@this err"/>
                <f:ajax event="blur" render="#{cc.attrs.renderParent}" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.renderParent}"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <h:panelGroup id="err">
            <utils:fieldError_right id="errText" group="#{cc.clientId}-txtInput"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

And I have a command button like below..

```
<h:commandButton id="btnNext" styleClass="btnNext" action="#{someBean.next}"/>
```

Now I am using the component in the following way...(just showing the bare bone representation)

```
 <util:numericInput label="Label" value="#{somebean.number}"
                           maxLength="2" optional="true" renderParent="-vehVal"

/>

    <h:panelGroup id="vehVal">
    <util:amountInput label="label2" value="#{someBean.nubmer2}"                    
                     rendered="#{someBean.number > 0}"
                     required="#{someBean.number > 0}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
```

So basically I want to render the "amountInput" component when ever user has entered some value > 0 in the "numericInput" component.
It works fine when I enter some value in the first field and click some where in the browser. But if I enter some value in the field and click on the next button directly it takes me to the next page, without validation (rendering) the next field. 
All I can understand is the onBlur event is not fired when I click on the next button. Why ?? Is there any solution??

Comment: Sorry guys I know my acccept rate is low, but I'm not sure how to increase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the event is fired, but the form is also being submitted, so the next view will be rendered and you'll miss the result of the ajax event.

You may have to use a more immediate event than `blur`, such as `keyup`. Additionally, you could conditionally disable the button if `someBean.number` is > 0 and `someBean.number2` is empty.

Comment: Exactly that is what is happening. Can not use key up as I want the validation to fire after the focus has moved away from the field, can not disable the button too, in that case the page validation is not going to happen. Actually I found a way to stay in the page using some condition in the next method of the bean but now I want the page level validation to fire too for that field which is not happening as in the first rendering phase only the second field is becoming visible but validation is not fired.

Comment: Okay used the keyup event to the compoment in the following way
 <f:ajax event="keyup" render="#{cc.attrs.renderParent}" disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.renderParent || not cc.attrs.renderKeyup}"/> 
worked like a charm :D